# What's a better method of pulling data from a console?

Tags: c#, minecraft

What's a better method of this to pull data without using a substantial amount of my CPU and ram, if possible? I'm using SwiftApi Bukkit plugin for Minecraft which uses Apache Thrift. Basically I'm trying to make a remote console. It currently works as I want it but at times it uses a lot of my CPU and sometimes RAM. So my question is, what's a better, less resource using, method of doing this?

```
private void getConsole2(Object state)
    {
        try
        {
            String authString = GetSHA256String("***************");
            TSocket socket = new TSocket("******", 21111);
            socket.Open();
            TBinaryProtocol protocol = new TBinaryProtocol(new TFramedTransport(socket));
            SwiftApi.Client client = new SwiftApi.Client(protocol);
            List<ConsoleLine> Console = client.getConsoleMessages(authString, (int)t.TotalSeconds);
            foreach (ConsoleLine c in Console)
            {
               //Filtering out some junk
                String line = Regex.Replace(c.ToString(), "[^\x0d\x0a\x20-\x7e\t]", "");
                line = line.Replace(",Level", "").Replace("[m", "").Replace("[0;33;22m", "").Replace("[0;37;1m", "").Replace("[0;31;1m", "").Replace("[0;37;22m", "").Replace("[0;36;1m", "").Replace("[0;34;22m", "").Replace("[0;36;22m", "").Replace("[0;31;22m", "").Replace("[0;35;1m", "").Replace("[0;30;1m", "").Replace("[0;32;1m", "").Replace("[0;32;22m", "").Replace("[0;35;22m", "").Replace("[0;34;1m", "").Replace("[0;30;22m", "").Replace("[0;33;1m", "").Replace("[3m", "");
                string[] s = line.Split(':');
                string part1 = s[1].Replace(",Message", "").Replace(" ", "");

                richTextBox2.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    if (!richTextBox2.Text.Contains(ConvertUnixTimeStamp(part1) + " [" + s.Last().Replace(" ", "").Replace(")", "") + "] " + s[2] + s[3].Replace(s.Last(), "")))
                    {
                        if (s.Last().Replace(" ", "").Replace(")", "").Equals("SEVERE"))
                        {
                            richTextBox2.Select(richTextBox2.TextLength, 0);
                            richTextBox2.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
                            richTextBox2.AppendText(System.Environment.NewLine + ConvertUnixTimeStamp(part1) + " [" + s.Last().Replace(" ", "").Replace(")", "") + "] " + s[2] + s[3].Replace(s.Last(), ""));
                            if (checkBox2.Checked == true) richTextBox2.ScrollToCaret();
                        }
                        else if (s.Last().Replace(" ", "").Replace(")", "").Equals("WARNING"))
                        {
                            richTextBox2.Select(richTextBox2.TextLength, 0);
                            richTextBox2.SelectionColor = Color.Orange;
                            richTextBox2.AppendText(System.Environment.NewLine + ConvertUnixTimeStamp(part1) + " [" + s.Last().Replace(" ", "").Replace(")", "") + "] " + s[2] + s[3].Replace(s.Last(), ""));
                            if (checkBox2.Checked == true) richTextBox2.ScrollToCaret();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            richTextBox2.Select(richTextBox2.TextLength, 0);
                            richTextBox2.SelectionColor = Color.FromArgb(205, 205, 205);
                            richTextBox2.AppendText(System.Environment.NewLine + ConvertUnixTimeStamp(part1) + " [" + s.Last().Replace(" ", "").Replace(")", "") + "] " + s[2] + s[3].Replace(s.Last(), ""));
                            if (checkBox2.Checked == true) richTextBox2.ScrollToCaret();
                        }
                    }
                }));
            }
            socket.Close();
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new System.Threading.WaitCallback(getConsole2));
        }
```

Comment: If this is periodically spiking CPU and RAM it sounds like the garbage collector is under a lot of memory pressure which would force it to dig into generation 1 & 2. This could be from your string handling. Replace() does not work inline, it creates a new string.

Comment: If you want to remove several characters, leading or trailing, use trim(with array of characters to remove) instead to reduce new string creation.